# Visual Studio error - Unknown compiler(s)

Tags: python, statsmodels, pmdarima

Versions:

```
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.4
qtconsole        : 4.7.7
ipython          : 8.5.0
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.7
jupyter lab      : 2.2.6
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.8
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

pip 22.3.1

I tried installing `pmdarima` using pip on Jupyter Notebook as well as Anaconda Promt, and encountered the same error as below. Kindly help me in figuring out how shall I get rid of this error.

```
!pip install pmdarima
```

Error:

```
    Collecting pmdarima
      Using cached pmdarima-2.0.2.tar.gz (630 kB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.17.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: Cython!=0.29.18,!=0.29.31,>=0.29 in c:\users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.29.21)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in c:\users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pmdarima) (1.23.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.19 in c:\users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pmdarima) (1.5.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.22 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.23.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.3.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pmdarima) (1.5.2)
    Collecting statsmodels>=0.13.2
      Using cached statsmodels-0.13.5.tar.gz (18.4 MB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'


error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [62 lines of output]
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.11"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring scipy: markers 'python_version == "3.7"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring scipy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_machine == "x86"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring scipy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_machine == "x86"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring scipy: markers 'python_version >= "3.12"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools>=59.2.0
    Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
  Collecting wheel>=0.37.1
    Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
  Collecting cython<3,>=0.29.32
    Using cached Cython-0.29.32-py2.py3-none-any.whl (986 kB)
  Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
    Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
  Collecting scipy<1.10,>=1.3
    Using cached scipy-1.9.3.tar.gz (42.1 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Installing backend dependencies: started
    Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1
  
    [21 lines of output]
    + meson setup --prefix=c:\users\hp\anaconda3 C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8637tmd9\scipy_a43633ab0f4d4afab54b7f1dfeb52603 C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8637tmd9\scipy_a43633ab0f4d4afab54b7f1dfeb52603\.mesonpy-8uh3dh8d\build --native-file=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8637tmd9\scipy_a43633ab0f4d4afab54b7f1dfeb52603\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
    The Meson build system
    Version: 1.0.0
    Source dir: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8637tmd9\scipy_a43633ab0f4d4afab54b7f1dfeb52603
    Build dir: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8637tmd9\scipy_a43633ab0f4d4afab54b7f1dfeb52603\.mesonpy-8uh3dh8d\build
    Build type: native build
    Project name: SciPy
    Project version: 1.9.3
    WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe
  
    ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
    The following exception(s) were encountered:
    Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  
    A full log can be found at C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8637tmd9\scipy_a43633ab0f4d4afab54b7f1dfeb52603\.mesonpy-8uh3dh8d\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
    [end of output]
  
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: metadata-generation-failed
  
  Encountered error while generating package metadata.
  
  See above for output.
  
  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for details.
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: You need to install Visual C++ compilers to Windows. Your error is not related to pip/python. Otherwise, what happens when you use `conda install pmdarima`?

Comment: Refer https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: @OneCricketeer I did as you suggested to install Visual C++. I am still getting the error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you installed. As the logs say, it's looking for commands like `gcc --version`, so if you cannot run those manually, then you'll still get the same error

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sir the error message has changed slightly in between after installing Visual C++. I believe I have messed up saving and running programs in different directories due to drive space, which is causing the issue. I will try on my end and update once done.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I had 32-bit version of Anaconda installed on my system with 64-bit processor. Had to reinstall the correct version which solved the issue.